# Let n be an even integer. How many different ways can I choose subsets of the set {1,2...,n}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let n be an even integer. How many
different ways can I choose subsets of
the set {1,2...,n} if they all have to
have odd size, but the intersection of
any two of them has to have even
size?

Please help me answer this question or lead me in the right direction. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This problem is known as odd-town.

Note: $n$ is even is irrelevant to the question.

Consider the incidence matrix with rows of subsets and columns of elements.

**Claim:** The column vectors are linearly independent.

Proof: Consider the dot product with $v_i$, over the field of 2 elements.

Hence, there are at most $n$ of them.

It remains to find $n$ subsets which satisfy the condition. This is easily done, by taking all the 1-element subsets.